# Adding product attribute column to edit order page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

Any help with this greatly appreciated.

Tried a number of things so far to no avail, including the suggestions here:
[Add product short description to Woocommerce admin orders preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49755552/add-product-short-description-to-woocommerce-admin-order-edit-pages)

This is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'custom_admin_order_items_headers', 20, 1 );
function custom_admin_order_items_headers( $order ){

    echo '<th>';
    echo __('Colour', 'woocommerce') . '</th>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'custom_admin_order_item_values', 20, 3 );
function custom_admin_order_item_values( $_product, $item, $item_id ) {
             
    $colour = $_product->get_attribute( 'colour' );
    echo '<td>' . $colour . '</td>';
}
```

Every product has a number of attributes, and I want to display one of these attributes in a new column on the edit order page.

The problem is the product attribute is empty for some reason - if I just echo $_product, there is no data in the attribute even though there definitely is a value for it saved in the DB.

Any ideas?

I've attached a screenshot of what I would like to achieve, and while I can get the header to display fine, and even an array of data attached to the product, the actual attribute is empty. If I use:

```
$_product->get_attribute( 'colour' )
```

like I do everywhere else on the site successfully, i get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_attribute() on null
```

I tried setting global $product; in the function, nada.

[image]

Error log:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_attribute() on null in /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php:1237 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): custom_admin_order_item_values(NULL, Object(WC_Order_Item_Shipping), 26) #1 /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-shipping.php(53): do_action('woocommerce_adm...', NULL, Object(WC_Order_Item_Shipping), 26) #4 /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php(73): include('/home/customer/...') #5 /home/customer/www/mysite in /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 1237

Line on 1237 of `functions.php` is:

```
$colour = $_product->get_attribute( 'colour' );
```

As stated above.

Comment: I have created one attribute called "colour" from Products->Attributes menu.I had copied your code and checked in my local environment , code is working fine and i got attribute value under colour column in order page. Kindly check if there is typo.Thanks.

Comment: Hi @anujpatel - thanks for your response - there is no typo, I checked again and in fact the code does work - it outputs the data, but above this I am getting a critical error alert:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_attribute() on null in /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php:1237 Stack trace: #0 /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): custom_admin_order_item_values(NULL, Object(WC_Order_Item_Shipping), 26)

Comment: #1 /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-shipping.php(53): do_action('woocommerce_adm...', NULL, Object(WC_Order_Item_Shipping), 26) #4 /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php(73): include('/home/customer/...')

Comment: #5 /home/customer/www/mysite in /home/customer/www/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php on line 1237

Comment: You can add above error log to your question :). Also it says there is error on line 1237 of functions.php file. Can post code of functions.php related to this error ?

Comment: Done. The problem line is the get_attributes() line posted above, but I've updated my post on your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3);
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {

    $colour = get_the_terms( $_product->post->ID, 'pa_colour');
    echo '<td>' . $colour[0]->name . '</td>';
}
```

Had to go down the route of taxonomy and not get_attribute(). Thanks to this post:

[show product meta in order items table in Order Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644420/show-product-meta-in-order-items-table-in-order-details/25645735#25645735)

Comment: Is there any other solution for displaying the Attributes value in the order details column? I tried to use this solution, but the data does not display, but there is an error message.

Comment: What attribute are you trying to display? This will work for a custom taxonomy called 'colour'. change `pa_colour` to `pa_yourcustomtax` and it should work.