# Adding variable product attribute column in WooCommerce edit order page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, orders

Based on [Adding product attribute column to edit order page in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59072299/11987538) answer code I wrote this function:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_item_headers', 'custom_admin_order_items_headers', 20, 1 );
function custom_admin_order_items_headers( $order ){

    echo '<th>';
    echo __('Marchio', 'woocommerce') . '</th>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3);
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {

    $marchio = get_the_terms( $_product->post->ID, 'pa_marchio');
    echo '<td>' . $marchio[0]->name . '</td>';
}
```

It works for simple products but not with variable products, how can fix it?

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get product ID use

```
$item->get_product_id()
```

Your function should look like this

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 'my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values', 10, 3);
function my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values($_product, $item, $item_id = null) {

    $marchio = get_the_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'pa_marchio');
    echo '<td>' . $marchio[0]->name . '</td>';

}
```

Check this post for more information how to access orders [Accessing Order Items protected data in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43597491/accessing-order-items-protected-data-in-woocommerce-3)

Comment: Works but now in order admin panel there are a error and I can't edit the order or other thinks:

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Order_Item_Shipping::get_product_id() in /home2/qerbellt/public_html/wp-content/themes/woodmart-child/functions.php:39

Comment: Stack trace:
#0 /home2/qerbellt/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): my_woocommerce_admin_order_item_values(NULL, Object(WC_Order_Item_Shipping), 6)
#1 /home2/qerbellt/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 /home2/qerbellt/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)

Comment: #3 /home2/qerbellt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-shipping.php(58): do_action('woocommerce_adm...', NULL, Object(WC_Order_Item_Shipping), 6)
#4 /home2/qerbellt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php(81): include('/home2/qerbellt...')
#5 /home2/qerbellt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-order-items.php(41): include('/home2/qerbellt...')
#6 /home2/q